# How can using scrapy to login scrapy without form element

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to login some website but it seems to be that they do not use form to display login dialog. So when using FormRequest, i got error

```
raise ValueError("No <form> element found in %s" % response)
```

So how can i login with scrapy in this case?

I try to find a form element in this website (using chrome devtool with xpath //form)  but the result is zero

It's login element is

```
<div class="loginModalBody">
            <div class="coverLoginModal">
                <p class="loginModalTitle">Login </p>

                    <div class=""><p class="login-msg"></p></div>

                    <!-- Email -->
                    <div class="loginCoverInputText">
                        <input class="loginInputText" id="email-login" role="presentation" autocomplete="off" type="email" name="loginEmail" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <span class="loginNameInputText">E-mail</span>
                        <span class="loginLineInputText"></span>
                        <!-- Error email -->
                        <div class="dontEnterEmail loginErrorInput"><p class="loginError">Vui lòng nhập email<span class="loginIconError"></span></p></div>
                        <div class="loginEmailInvalid loginErrorInput"><p class="loginError">Invalid email<span class="loginIconError"></span></p></div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div class="loginCoverInputText">
                        <input class="loginInputText" id="password-login" autocomplete="new-password" type="password" name="loginPassword" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="loginNameInputText">Password</span>
                        <span class="loginLineInputText"></span>
                        <!-- Error password -->
                        <div class="dontEnterPassword loginErrorInput"><p class="loginError">Enter password<span class="loginIconError"></span></p></div>
                    </div>


                    <!-- Remember password -->
                    <label class="loginRememberPassword" id="login-remember-pass" for="loginRememberPassword"><input id="loginRememberPassword" type="checkbox" name="loginRememberPassword"><span></span>Ghi nhớ mật khẩu</label>
                    <p class="loginForgotPassword forgot-password"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dismiss="modal"><span></span>forgot pass</a></p>

                    <button class="loginButtonSubmit btn-login" id="btn-login-system" type="button">Login</button>


                <p class="loginDontAccount">Do not have account? <a class="not-account" href="javascript:void(0)" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-signup-system">Register!</a></p>
                <p class="loginOr">Or</p>

                <button type="button" class="loginByGoogle" onclick="open_login_g()">Login with Google</button>
                <button type="button" class="loginByFacebook" onclick="open_login_f()">Login with Facebook</button>

            </div>
        </div>
```

The code i use is

```
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "card"
    start_urls = ["https://website/auth/signin"]
    login_user = "foo"
    login_pass = "bar"

    def parse(self, response):
        '''Parse login page'''
        open_in_browser(response)
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                'email':"username",
                'password': "pass"
            },
            callback=self.parse_home
        )

    def parse_home(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        print response
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web scraping is about requests and responses, so all you need is simulate all user requests. `FormRequest` just helps us to avoid extra work with forms. In this case you need make a proper login [Request](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request).

1. Go to needed page and open developer tools in your browser (e.g. Chrome)
2. Check a `preserve log` option in `Network` tab.
3. Fill credentials at the page and push `login` button.
4. Find out the login request (after button was pressed)
5. Check `Headers` tab in the request and find out request type and parameters (it can be GET with some querystring parameters or POST with some `Form Data`
6. In your code try to reproduce the login request using a simple scrapy [Request](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) instead of `FormRequest`